# Query Calculation at lower granularity

Tags: report, aggregation, cognos

So I have a report that shows. Product, account type, account tier, balance, # of deposits.

My problem is that I need the tier to be applied to the individual accounts based off of their balance. So if your account is less than 99 then 'TIER 1', 100-199 then 'TIER 2' and > 200 then 'TIER 3'. The issue with this is the tier needs to be summarized. So the logic needs to be at account granularity but then just show the different combinations of product, account type and account tier. The balance also needs to be the total of everyone within that group.

example:

```
    PRODUCT | TYPE | TIER | BALANCE | # OF DEPOSITS
       A    |  1   |  T1  | $95,000 |       4
       A    |  1   |  T2  | $80,000 |      10
       A    |  1   |  T3  |$100,000 |       2
       A    |  2   |  T1  | $50,000 |      45
       A    |  2   |  T2  | $70,000 |      13
       A    |  2   |  T3  |$250,000 |     100
       B    |  1   |  T1  | $65,000 |      45
       B    |  1   |  T2  | $15,000 |      25
       etc...
```

I hope this at least shows what I am trying to accomplish with this report.
Please feel free to ask questions for more clarification.

Thank you in advance-

EDIT: This is the output I am currently getting.

```
  PRODUCT | TYPE | TIER | BALANCE | # OF DEPOSITS
       A    |  1   |  T1  | $1MIL   |      100
       A    |  2   |  T1  | $1.5MIL |      520
       A    |  3   |  T6  | $2MIL   |      650
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming the column 'Tier' is generated by you and not from the data source.

[Tier]

```
CAST 
WHEN [Balance] < 99 THEN 'Tier1'
WHEN [Balance] between 100 and 199 THEN 'Tier2' 
WHEN [Balance] > 200 THEN 'Tier3'
END
```

[Total Balance]

```
total([Balance] for [Product],[Type],[Tier])
```

Set the [Total Balance] Aggregate Function property to 'Calculated'.

Comment: this is what I have currently but it looks like it is adding all the accounts together first and then applying the tier logic. I am not sure it is very starnge

Comment: I think the output in your original question is the output you desire. Can you also provide the output you are actually getting? Also, more information about the data domain would be helpful.

Comment: I put my current output in the original post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, a crosstab to aggregate the three criteria might be the best solution.

or

A clunky but effective way might be to create a two queries (I assume you are using report studio). The first to assign each account a tier, and in the next query you can add the total aggregate.